# Apache 2.4: mod_php vs php-fpm performance

Tags: php-fpm, php5, benchmark, apache-2.4, mod-php

There are plenty of old benchmarks on Apache mod_php vs nginx with php-fpm

However, with version 2.4, Apache can use php-fpm. Are there any sensible benchmarks comparing mod_php with php-fpm (both on Apache 2.4.x)?

Comment: While `mod_proxy_fcgi` is new, `mod_fastcgi` lets you use PHP-FPM with versions older than 2.4.  Not sure how their performance compares, though.

Answer (score 4):

I'm working for a hosting/cloud company and we routinely use Apache 2.2 + mod_fastcgi + php-fpm (socket listen).

It uses a little more memory and CPU, but it's much more faster than mod_cgi/mod_php/mod_suphp.

If you can choose, go with mod_proxy_fcgi + php-fpm (2.4) or mod_fastcgi + php-fpm

Comment: Thanks! That is helpful. Would like to see some hard, objective measures as well.